# how to get average score in php

Tags: php, mysqli

i want to calculate average on run time by totalscore/totalevaluatedcalls which is 100.how can i did it with php...and after table here is my code.any one can help me in this regard .total evaluated calls are the count of emp id from db.

```
empid    agentname    totalevaluatedcalls     totalscore     avaragescore
=========================================================================
1       xyz            2                      200             100


total evaluatedcalls query
========================== 

foreach($dbh->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM eval where empid=$empid") as $test) {  
    echo "<table ><tr ><td style='border: 0px; '>" . $test['cnt'] . "</td></tr></table>";
}

?>

total score query
========================== 


foreach($dbh->query("SELECT SUM(totalscore) as cnt FROM eval where empid = $empid") as $leavecount) {  
    echo "<table ><tr ><td style='border: 0px; ' >" . $leavecount['cnt'] . "</td></tr></table>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine this queries

```
foreach($dbh->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt, SUM(totalscore) as totalscore, SUM(totalscore)/SUM(totalevaluatedcalls) as averagescore
                FROM eval 
                where empid= $empid 
           ") as $test) 
                     {  
echo "<table ><tr ><td style='border: 0px; '>" . $test['cnt'] . "</td><td style='border: 0px; '>" . $test['totalscore'] . "</td><td style='border: 0px; '>" . $test['averagescore'] . "</td></tr></table>";    

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

use query as

```
foreach($dbh->query("select count(*) as cnt,sum(totalscore) as tot from eval where empid=$empid") as $data)
{
   $avg=($data['cnt']/$data['tot'])*100;
}
```